# importing .dmp file in oracle 10g express edition

Tags: import, oracle10g

I am having a problem while using the below command in the windows operating system and I have installed the oracle 10g server on my local machine which I am able to connect using client IDE

When I try to use the below command to import a dump file in my local DB

"imp system/ file=tms.dump log=test.log" in command prompt

where the binary of imp and the dump file is located in
"C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\bin"

I am getting the below error

error: unable to write logfile

I do not know how to create the log file

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely reason for the error is that you are using an account which doesn't have write privileges on `bin`.  You haven't specified a path, so like most utilities, `imp` will write its log files to the current directory.

`bin` is traditionally the sub-directory for holding executables.  It is a *very bad idea* to use it for storing application data such as dump files.

Instead you should be working from a different location, ideally some sub-directory which you use solely for storing dump files.  Either way, it must be a directory for which your user has write privileges.

Comment: i have moved my .dmp file into D drive and i am using this command in cmd:
C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\bin\ imp system\123 file= D:\DB\tms.dmp log=tms.log
and i still get this errors
1. unaable to create log file
please help

Comment: thanku its worked
we have to give full path in log file